# How to attach Micronew Sti Shifter to handlebar

Tags: shifter, brifters

I bought a pair of Micronew R7 2x7 sti shifters.  They don't come with a manual but look almost exactly like the Microshift sti shifters.

I looked inside the shifter while holding down the brake handle but I can't see any screws to tighten.  Since these seem almost identical to the Microshift sti, I also looked along the sides but I don't see anywhere screws of any kind to fasten.

Would any happen to be familiar with these shifters and how to fasten them?

Comment: Have you looked under the rubber? There has to be a screw attached to the metal sleeve somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MicroNEW is a Chinese manufacturer of bike and motorcycle parts.  They are in no way associated with Microshift,  and have copied the design of Microshift shifters.  [See the comments section of this blog](https://road.cc/content/forum/254023-microshift-r-series-r8r9-groupset) for some words, apparently from Microshift, regarding issues of these knock-offs.

So, assuming the forgeries are accurate copies of Microshift R9 brifters, one accesses the clamp band bolt (typically will be a hex cap bolt) from the front and outer aspect of the shifter. If you gently pry the hood away from the front outer aspect of the shifter you should be able to see the hex bolt head and engage it with a longish hex wrench (the long side of an L shaped Allen key, or the long part of a P-handle hex wrench).  The [installation instructions for the Microshift versions](https://www.microshift.com/models/sb-r492/) can be downloaded from their R9 description/spec page.

Here's a screenshot of the brifters that highlight the clamp bolt access.  Tightening torque is 6-8 N-m and if you are installing on carbon fiber drop bars you'll need to confirm with the bar manufacturer the proper torque that should be used as it may be different.

[image: Microshift brifter install]